# Why is this recursive algorithm wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a problem with this method I've written in Java.

The method is to take two strings. The first string `sArr` is to track the letters added as the second string is parsed. The second string `str` is a string of integers, where each integer is used in sequence to add to `sArr`. 
Each integer refers to a different array of letters, for example:

```
 String[] two = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

At the moment it is an auxiliary method for another one. 
If I input anything, it will only make use of the first digit entered. It's supposed to output all the permutations of the sets from the digits. So input of 22 would output: `AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC`

The test input I've been using has been `printStrAux("", 23);`
And the subsequent output is all the letters from the set of `2` which would look like: `ABC`

I don't necessarily want to be spoonfed answers, but any help would be wonderful.

```
public static void printStrings(String str){
    if(isAllDigits(str))
        System.out.println(printStrAux("", str));
}

protected static String printStrAux(String sArr, String str){
    if(str.equals(""))
        return sArr;


    else{

        Integer val = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1));

        switch (val) {
        case 1: printStrAux(sArr, str.substring(1));
        break;
        case 2: 
            for(int i = 0; i < two.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += two[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 3: 
            for(int i = 0; i < three.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += three[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;

        case 4:  
            for(int i = 0; i < four.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += four[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 5:  
            for(int i = 0; i < five.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += five[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 6:  
            for(int i = 0; i < six.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += six[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 7:  
            for(int i = 0; i < seven.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += seven[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 8:  
            for(int i = 0; i < eight.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += eight[i], str.substring(1));
            }

        break;
        case 9:  
            for(int i = 0; i < nine.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += nine[i], str.substring(1));

        }
        break;
        case 0:  {
            printStrAux(sArr, str.substring(1));
        }
        break;


        }

    }
    return sArr;
}
```

Keep in mind that I almost have no real clue as to what I'm doing here instead of what I wanted.

Comment: 1. Document clearly the method's contract (what it's supposed to do). 2. Format the code (indent, remove unnecesary braces in case)

Comment: What are the arrays `two`, `three` etc?

Comment: @leonbloy I've done as requested, does that look better or is the contract still unclear? (If so, how can I clarify it?)
@slim The arrays `two` and `three` contain letters that correspond to digits taken via `str` in the method call...

Comment: StackOverflow is really best suited to generalized questions where others can learn from the question and answer; "please review this code" (without that code being simplified to demonstrate that single concept or process in as few lines as possible, and a description that points clearly at that concept) isn't a great use, and exactly the use case for the "close as too localized" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step back and think about the fundamentals of recursion. It would probably help if you got rid of all the cases except for *empty list* and *list beginning with '2'* for now. Put cases in for the other digits later.

The pattern for a collecting recursive function like this one is:

```
private Type func(Type accumulator, List input) {
    if(input.size() == 0) {
        return accumulator;
    } else {
        Type myAccumulated = someOperation(accumulator, input.head());
        return func(myAccumulated, input.tail();
    }
}
```

(I have pretended that List.head() and List.tail() exist, for brevity. You achieve those with substring()).

In your case, `Type` is String and you're using a String as a list of characters.

Work on adapting that general pattern. One fundamental thing you're not doing, is capturing the output of your recursive call to `func()` and incorporating that in what you return to your caller.

---

Aside from recursion:

- Consider making your `Type` a data structure like a List<List<Char>> rather than a String. It will probably be easier to reason about, and you can write another method to convert it to a String.
- Rather than having variables called `two`, `three` etc., have an array of sequences. `sequences[2] = {"A","B","C"}`. Then you won't need a bunch of near-identical `case` blocks.

Comment: So, the general shape of a recursive algorithm would be something like:
`Base case`
`output capture`
`recursive call(output, otherInput)`

Comment: It's "if nothing to do {return unchanged}, else {do my portion of the work, make recursive call for remainder of work, return the result}"

Answer (score 1):

In your recursive calls to printStrAux, you don't keep the returned value sArr.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm unsure how that would be implemented?
Do you mean I shouldn't return sArr, or should I use a different value in the recursive call?

Comment: in the code: `for(int i = 0; i < two.length; i++){
                printStrAux(sArr += two[i], str.substring(1));
            }` the retun of printStrAux is never used, sArr is passed by value and is not changed, so you should do: `sArr = printStrAux(sArr += two[i], str.substring(1));`

Answer (score 1):

When you recursively call your method, you need to catch the return value of it, f.e.:

```
sArr = printStrAux(sArr += two[i], str.substring(1));
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and the output isn't really right at all. Is there another way to catch the return value?